# Explain keras code snippet

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have this piece of code :

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Dense(32)(a)
```

in `Dense(32)(a)`    I know that we are creating `keras.layers.Dense` object but what does `(a)` part to `Dense(32)` object we create?

Also how does python understand it internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part `b = Dense(32)(a)` creates a `Dense` layer that receives tensor `a` as input. It is done this way to allow using the same dense layer with different inputs (i.e. to allow sharing weights).

For example, consider the following snippet:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

a = Input(shape=(32,))
b = Input(shape=(32,))
dense = Dense(32)
c = dense(a)
d = dense(b)
```

Here, `dense = Dense(32)` instantiates a `Dense` layer, which is callable. You could think of it as if you were creating a function that you can call on different inputs (i.e. `c = dense(a)` and `d = dense(b)`). This is provides a very convenient way of sharing weights.

Comment: In keras/layers/ directory of keras source code, I do not find Input definition as we see it from 
`from keras.layers import Input`. 
Where can I find the definition of Input?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L1377

Comment: In `c = dense(a)` snippet what function will be called? Are we creating a dense instance?

Comment: Right, we're creating a dense instance with `dense = Dense(32)`. It is not exactly a function but a callable. In python, a callable is anything that you can call. An instance of a class is said to be callable if it implements a `__call__` method. Then, when you write `c = dense(a)`, the function that is being called is this one: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L842

Comment: To be precise: in `dense=Dense(32)` you're creating a dense instance. In the following two lines you are "passing an input tensor to an existing dense layer to get an output tensor".